# How to re-install Linux from bootable usb stick?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I’m trying to re-install Linux with a bootable usb stick. After I entered the bios model and saw the device under the submenu of boot, I just couldn’t open it or enter it to start the installation. Very confused.... By the way the creation of the bootable usb from ISOs was done by startup disk creator. I think something went wrong but I can’t figure it out.

[image: Screenshot of bios]

Comment: You can't "enter" a device from the bios menu. When you create bootable installation media you have to choose whether to auto load "setup.exe" or boot to a state that allows you to enter a command.  Add to your question: A link to the guide you used to create installation media.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think the problem had nohting to do with the bootable installation. Like gronostaj said, I just entered a wrong menu and I should have used F12. And I found the real boot menu and successfully solved the problem :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a boot menu, that's boot order editor.

Boot menu is usually accessible using <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Or alternatively you can move your USB drive to the top of the list - instructions are on the right half of the screen on your photo. Your boot mode is UEFI first, so the EFI list will take priority, not Legacy one.